# Standing waves in a resonance tube

Tags: waves, home-experiment, resonance

I am doing an experiment about standing waves in a resonance tube. I use a bucket of water, a waterproof tube (open at both ends), and a frequency generator app. I have two set-ups, A and B:

A. Setting the frequency to be constant and dipping the tube into the bucket of water until I hear resonance that signifies standing waves. I record the effective length of tube at which this occurs, from the part where the tube touches the water to the other end. Then, I compute the corresponding wavelengths.

B. Setting the length to be constant but with increasing frequency. I record the frequency at which the standing waves occur and compute the wavelengths.

Using the formula for the speed of sound $v =$ wavelength x frequency, I have solved the experimental speed of sound. Now, using the room temperature to solve for the theoretical speed of sound, I found out that the Set B resulted to less deviation from this theoretical value compared to the case of Set A. Is this expected in general? What do you think are the main sources of error?

Comment: Welcome JD Maximo. An interesting question, but you might want to provide a bit more experimental detail. For example, how big a deviation are you talking about? Did you monitor temperature continuously, or just once? What was the uncertainty in the length and frequency measurement?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same apparatus to either, **1** detect a maximum loudness whilst altering the length or, **2** detecting a maximum loudness whilst altering the frequency.

From your post it would appear that method **2** allows you to estimate the maximum loudness with greater precision which is perhaps no surprise as I think that I would find it easier to twiddle a knob to change the frequency in "comfort" and estimate the frequency for maximum loudness as oppose to moving a tube up and down whilst keeping it vertical and setting the tube at estimated maximum loudness.

I do not know how you analysed your data but you as you have not mentioned an [end correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_correction), $e$, for the tube which is a correction for the fact the the displacement node (pressure node) does no occur exactly at the open end of the tube.
This means that for the fundamental resonance position $L+e= \lambda/4$ where $L$ is the physical length of the tube and $\lambda$ the wavelength of the sound.

$\dfrac {\lambda}{4} = \dfrac cf \Rightarrow L = \dfrac {4c}{f}-e $ where $f$ is the frequency of the sound  and $c$ the speed of sound.
So a graph of $L$ against $\dfrac 1f$ has a gradient of $4c$ and an intercept on the $L$ axis of $-e$.

Note also that if you do not account for the end correction it produces a smaller error in the estimate of the wavelength the larger the wavelength (the smaller the frequecncy) is.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to comment on a specific experimental setup, but I am not surprised by your result.  In B, the machine can control the value of the frequency much more precisely than you can manually submerge the tube into the water to a certain length in A.

One thing to try calculating is, if your length measurement is off by say $\mathrm{0.1 \, cm, 0.5 \, cm, \,or\, 1 \, cm}$, what % change does that produce in the speed of sound result?

Another thing to assess is whether your Method A results seem to be consistently too high, too low, or randomly scattered around the true value.